# Check if string matches specific format

Tags: regex

I have a string and I want to check if it matches the correct format. This is correctly formatted string:

```
key=3aaae
1:  txt
0:  foo

key=fffff
1:  foo
0:  bar
0:  foo
1:  foooooo.

key=eeeee
1:  Bar
```

This pattern `key=[\da-f]{5,10}(?:\n[01]:.*)+` return multiple matches, but how can I make it return one match of the whole string?

Comment: To validate the whole string you may use something like `^key=[\da-f]{5,10}(?:\n+[01]:.*)+(?:\nkey=[\da-f]{5,10}(?:\n[01]:.*)+)*$`, see https://regex101.com/r/0RFeHc/1

Comment: `^(?:key=[\da-f]{5,10}(?:\n[01]:.*)+\n+)+`? Demo: https://regex101.com/r/VF8r21/1

Comment: You may consider `^(?:key=[\da-f]{5,10}(?:\n[01]:.*)+\n*)+` for single match